# Magento 2: Multiple Cart rules not working at a time

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules, discount, coupon

I have two Cart rules, Both rules "discard subsequent rules" set to No.

1. This cart rule providing 10% discount if someone adding a specific
   product with minimum quantity 2, no coupon or no other restrictions
2. This cart rule providing 5% discount if someone use a specific coupon, can be applied to any products in the cart.

Here both rules working fine while use individually but **while use both rules at a time** 2nd rule overriding the 1st rule, **only applying 5% coupon discount** not 10% + 5%, here discount supposed to be 15% of subtotal but I am only getting 5%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a Magento bug: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2931

See a commit here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/d66748032936d4f48c937343a9906fea8acdd132

Seems to be fixed in CE 2.1.3.

Comment: Yes your are right, this commit helped me to fix the issue
https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/d66748032936d4f48c937343a9906fea8acdd132

I would like to update to 2.1.3 , but you know what are the other fixes updated on the latest version? and is any new issue reported with the latest version? when 2.1.4 release?

Comment: You should read Release notes: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/release-notes/bk-release-notes.html

Comment: I'm on 2.1.5 and it still doesn't seem to be fixed. Specifically I'm trying to add a multiple coupon codes to the same cart. Maybe that's not possible?